# Heap Space Size?

Tags: android, gradle, heap-size

I have a db file(300mb) in my assets folder.When I am running the code it gives me below error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Java heap space
ect's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
<em>org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m</em>
<a href="http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html">Read Gradle's configuration guide</a><br><a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html">Read about Java's heap size</a>
```

Below is gradle.properties

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.


# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true


org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I tried lot of things like changing **_JAVA_OPTIONS** in environment variable, Changing values in **studio.exe.vmoptions** and **gradle.properties** but it is giving me the same error.

Please help

Comment: why you have 300MB in assets instead of using expansion file? https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: Actually I have to work on this file for a day or two,after that the size will reduced to 50MB so I did not go for file expansion. What do you suggest?

Comment: using expansion file. This data is most likely not changing so no point bloating main APK

Comment: I understood your point Marcin but the thing is I don't have to publish the apk with this db file.The db file will be downloaded from the server after user log in to the app. So for now to write the db queries I am putting it in assets folder.Is there any way to solve the above error??

Comment: what about setting heap bigger than 1MB? like 2 or so? have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try increasing java heap size. Here are the steps:

Look for memory indicator in bottom right corner of Android Studio

[image]

If you don't see this option, enable it from Android Studio Preferences > Appearance and Behaviour > Appearance > Show memory indicator

[image]

Increase java heap size: Choose Help > Edit custom VM Options

[image]

Update Xmx value in studio.vmoptions file that open when you select above option. For 8GB RAM I have added these values, you might need to adjust based on your system configuration:

```
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

You can also find this file in ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio

Restart Android Studio and see if your memory indicator displays updated values.